# com.esri.arcgis.runtime.error Code=10018 bad lexical cast

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis-runtime

I'm getting an issue while creating serviceFeatureTable from my layer url.

```
 let serviceFeatureTable = AGSServiceFeatureTable(url: selectableMapLayerUrl)
            serviceFeatureTable.load { (error) in
                if let error = error
                {
                    print(error) // bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
                }
}
```

**Error Is :**
Error Domain=com.esri.arcgis.runtime.error Code=10018 "bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target, NSLocalizedFailureReason=}

It is working perfectly on website but giving issue on iOS

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a domain defined on that layer where there's a type mismatch between the domain definition and the values on that domain. One example I've seen is that the domain's type is `esriFieldTypeSmallInteger` but the domain's values are doubles. Is that (or something like that) the case here?

If that's not the case, can you share the layer's URL or (if it's not public) the JSON?